# Why some words can not be saved into customer dictionary in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

When a word is displayed with a red underline, it means that this word is wrongly spelled or not in the dictionary. In the latter case, the word can be saved into the dictionary in `Check Spelling`.

But I have found that some words (either correctly spelled or personal names) are red underlined, however, it can not be saved into the dictionary because it never shows the word when doing `Check Spelling`. What is the problem?

**Edit:** Here is a short example:

In \cite[p214]{Kosko}, Kosko presents an inexact oval as a fuzzy ellipse to dispute a **Lindley**'s (can not be checked) claim \cite{Lindley}: \textit{Probability is the only sensible description of uncertainty and is adequate for all problems involving uncertainty. All other methods are inadequate}.

Obviously, Lindley's claim is wrong because not all uncertainty issues can be handled by probability. However, the fuzzy ellipse by Kosko is inadequate because it lacks mathematical rigor to define the exact degree of elliptical roundness.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I added a text where Lindley can not be checked. It is a name and spelling is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think this is very strange, but here's what I found myself, and a possible workaround. However, there is a bug here which should be reported to TeXStudio. (Here's [their issue tracker](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/). Let me know if you don't want to report it and I will.)

The first time you run Check Spelling on a document with both "Lindley" and "Lindley's" in it, it will find "Lindley" and you can add it to the dictionary. From then on, the non-possessive form "Lindley" is correctly handled and no longer highlighted.

However, although the underlining on the possessive form "Lindley's" is initially removed at the same time, it comes back if you reload the document or retype it or another misspelled word. Now when you do a "Check Spelling", it won't find it. You can temporarily remove the underlining by right clicking on it and choose "Add to dictionary" again, but the underlining will come back, because it only re-adds the non-possessive form.

*However*, you can manually add the possessive form to the dictionary if you click "Show User Words" at the bottom of the "Check Spelling" screen and then "Add" and then type in the possessive form. It should work from then on.

You can also directly edit the dictionary file, which for me on Linux is located at `$HOME/.config/texstudio/texstudioen_US.ign`.

However, these are both annoying workarounds, and a bug report should be filed. Again, I will if you don't want to.

(I'm using TeXStudio 4.2.2 on Archlinux BTW.)

Comment: @hermes I don't actually use TeXStudio myself. I only have it installed because people who know me often ask me to help with LaTeX stuff, and they use it. I don't *think* the dictionary is transferred with the profile if you transfer a profile from one computer to another, but I've never tried. Still, I'll report the bug.

Comment: @hermes I filed the bug report, and it looks like it was a simple fix, and so should be better in the next version of TeXStudio.

Comment: @hermes You'll need a github account, so make one if you don't have on already. Log in to github. Then go to the issue tracker link I put in my answer, and go to the "issues" tab, and click "New Issue". You probably want to search on the Issues page first to see if it's already been reported first though.